# EMF in circuits help?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics

Can someone explain EMF in the most simple way possible? I understand the equation i.e. $ε=I(R+r)$ but don't fully understand what is going on in the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conductor is made of neutral atoms, which has equal numbers of protons and electrons. The protons and some of the electrons are fixed. But some of the electrons, the "valence" electrons, can move freely in the conductor. Eletrons repel each other, so they tend to spread out as much as they can without leaving the conductor.

If you add extra electrons, electrons are closer together than they were. It takes work to make electrons approach each other against an electrostatic force of repulsion. This means the electrons gain potential energy. The EMF is the amount of potential energy per free electron. The name was poorly chosen. It is about energy per electron, which is related to force, but is not the same thing.

A battery has two terminals, and chemicals which drive electrons to one terminal. The electrons at the negative terminal are a little compressed and those at the positive terminal are a little spread out. Those at the negative terminal have a little more potential energy than those at the positive terminal.

In a battery, this is a small effect. The potential energy per electron is just a few Volts. The crowding is not enough where you notice that the terminals are charged.

If you shuffle your feet on a rug, enough electrons are transferred to raise the energy per electron to thousands of volts. The electrons are crowded or spread out enough (It can be hard to tell which.) to attract other charges, or even create a spark.

If you connect the battery to a circuit, electrons in the negative push each other out into the wire and flow to the positive terminal.

Chemical reactions in the battery keep sucking electrons off the positive terminal and pushing them to the negative terminal, until the battery runs out of chemicals.

Answer (score 2):

EMF is the total voltage that can be supplied by a source of electrical energy (e.g. battery/dynamo). Basically, it encompasses both the voltage that will reflect in the circuit and the voltage that is constantly used up to overcome the resistance r of the component itself.

Voltage is equivalent to work done per charge (V= W/q), this applies to EMF as work in order to move a positive charge through the source and circuit.

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The emf of the battery causes a potential drop across the circuit due to the chemical reactions inside the battery.
When a charge gets to the positive end of the battery(remember that in reality,in most cases it is the electrons that flow in a circuit and are moving from the negative end to the positive end of the battery) they get attracted by that positive end.So how do they manage to get out of the negative end of the battery then(when inside the battery,the electric field inside tends to keep it on the positive end-negative charges push it away from them and positive pull it towards them)?Well,its the EMF!
The chemical energy is what drives the charges against the electric field inside the battery.When they get out of the battery,then the electric field does not oppose their movement,so no problem there.
If you want any clarification as to why the emf is equal to I(R+r) just ask!
As to what it actually does in the circuit,it is the one that causes the charges to move and create a current so intense as to pass through the resistors of the system(it is the energy that a single charge has in order to get past the resistors and get to the other end of the battery having lost just the amount of energy to have the potential equal to the potential at the end of the battery that it will get to).
The emf is transformed into thermal energy when the charge passes through a resistor(and the wire because the wire has non-zero resistance).